# Draw regularPolygon from left to right in OpenLayers rather than center out

Tags: openlayers-2

When I draw a regular polygon in OpenLayers, it draws from the center out (like a circle). I would like it behave more like `Handler.Box` does (drawing from the UL corner to LR corner.) Is this possible or do I need to figure out how to get `Handler.Box` to work?

Whenever I use `Handler.Box` I get this error:

```
TypeError: feature.geometry.getBounds is not a function
var bounds = feature.geometry.getBounds();
```

Which is an error in the OpenLayers.js file.

I have all the code for Regular Polygon (all the after insert code and such) so I would prefer to get it to behave how I want. I couldn't find anything in the docs about it, or maybe I didn't understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the option irregular: true seems to solve it.